Show custom taxomony on custom single post type
Would love some help on a website I'm currently building because I seem to not get something to work. The website has a custom post type 'evenement'. I have created a custom taxonomy 'locatie' and last but not least I have made a Field group item 'evenement_locatie', linked to the custom taxonomy.
I made a template for that show's a single evenement post, that show's the custom fields which I get with this code
<p><?php the_field("event_startdate"); ?><br> om <?php the_field("event_starttime"); ?></p>

This works fine for all fields, however I can't seem to load the custom taxomony, and I tried all codes that I could find online. This is the code I'm currently using:
<?php $term = get_field('evenement_locatie');
if( $term ): ?>
<h2><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?>test</h2>
<p><?php echo esc_html( $term->description ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

And I have also tried
<?php echo get_field('evenement_locatie', get_queried_object()); ?>

Also tried to use the get_term function, but I can't figure out how to get it working.
I also trying using get_field('locatie') and that does not work as well.
My goal is to show the taxonomy title, and the description, but I've tried for hours now to get something. Also the WP_DEBUG is not giving me any error's as well, so don't know how to continue.
Any tips or tricks?
Thanks in advance!

I think the issue is when creating a taxonomy field in ACF, the default result value will be a term ID, not a term object. Your code is correct but it's only work with the term object only.
You can check the return value in ACF setting like this screenshot

There are 2 options here

Update the return value in ACF to Term Object so you can use the current code.
Use the new code below to get the field you need

<?php 
$term_id = get_field('evenement_locatie');
if($term_id):
    $term = get_term($term_id);
?>
    <h2><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?>test</h2>
    <p><?php echo esc_html($term->description); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

